Getting Unauthorised "Unauthorised" from Amazon SP-API when trying to access GET_LEDGER_SUMMARY_VIEW_DATA
I have a script that I am running to get inventory ledger. However despite the fact that my developer app has all permissions, I still keep getting unauthorised. Error reproduced below.
Error
'''
Getting access token
200
Status code: 403
Response content: {
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "Unauthorized",
      "message": "Access to the resource is forbidden",
      "details": ""
    }
  ]
}'''

The first status code is for getting access code from Amazon which is working. The next 403 is unauthorised. The code is reproduced below
     '''from sqlalchemy.sql import text
    import requests
    import urllib.parse
    from pprint import pprint
    from key_fba import credential
    from typing import List, Dict
    import time
    import gzip
    import json
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    import pandas as pd
    import csv
    import io
    import pyodbc
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    
    def get_access_token()-> str:
        url="https://api.amazon.co.uk/auth/o2/token"
        form_data={
            "grant_type": "refresh_token",
            "client_id": credential['client_id'],
            "client_secret": credential['client_secret'],
            "refresh_token": credential['refresh_token'],
            
            
        }
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
    #"scope": "profile"
    response = requests.post(url, data=form_data, headers=headers)
    print(response.status_code)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(f"Failed to get access token: {response.text}")
    else:
        access_token=response.json()['access_token']
        return access_token


    def check_completion(access_token: str, report_id: str)-> bool:
        url = f"https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com/reports/2021-06-30/reports/{report_id}"
        headers = {
        "x-amz-access-token": access_token,
        
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(f"Status code: {response.status_code}")
    print(f"Response content: {response.text}")
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(f"Failed to check report completion: {response.text}")
    while True:
        status = response.json()['processingStatus']
        if status == 'DONE':
            return response.json()['reportDocumentId']
        elif status in ['FATAL', 'CANCELLED']:
            return status
        else:
            time.sleep(30)
            response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            if response.status_code != 200:
                raise Exception(f"Failed to check report completion: {response.text}")

    def get_report(access_token: str) -> Dict:
        url = "https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com/reports/2021-06-30/reports"
        market_place_id = ["A21TJRUUN4KGV"]
        report_type = "GET_LEDGER_SUMMARY_VIEW_DATA"
        request_params = {
        "marketplaceIds": market_place_id,
        "reportType": report_type,
        "dataStartTime": (datetime.today() - timedelta(days=4)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
        "dataEndTime": (datetime.today() - timedelta(days=3)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
        "reportOptions": {
            "aggregateByLocation": "FC",  # Removed the trailing space
            "aggregatedByTimePeriod": "DAILY"
        }
    }
        headers = {
            "x-amz-access-token": access_token,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
    }
    
    response = requests.post(url, json=request_params, headers=headers)
    print(f"Status code: {response.status_code}")
    print(f"Response content: {response.text}")

    
    report = response.json()
    
    
    if 'reportId' not in report:
        raise KeyError("'reportId' not found in the response. Check the API response format.")
    
    report_id = report['reportId']
    # print(f'Report ID: {report_id}')
    return report_id, report_type
   

    def get_report_data(access_token: str, doc_id: str, report_type: str)-> Dict:
        url = f"https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com/reports/2021-06-30/documents/{doc_id}"
        headers = {
            "x-amz-access-token": access_token,
            
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    report_url = response.json()['url']
    
      

    r = requests.get(report_url)
    print(f"Response status code: {r.status_code}")

    content_type = r.headers.get('Content-Type', '')
    
    print(f"Content type: {content_type}")
    

    
    
    decoded=r.content.decode("cp1252")
    csv_data=csv.reader(io.StringIO(decoded), delimiter='\t')
    headers=next(csv_data)
    decoded_str=pd.DataFrame(csv_data, columns=headers)
    
    return decoded_str
# # ###==========================================================================Report Saving process===============================================================================================================

def save_report_to_sql_database(df):
    ******************************************
    
    # Write the DataFrame to SQL Server
    df.to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
    
    print(f"Successfully inserted {len(df)} rows of data into the SQL Database table '{table_name}'.")
 ###================================================================================================Report Saving Ends===========================================================================================   

    def script():
        print('Getting access token')
        access_token = get_access_token()
        report_id, report_type = get_report(access_token)
        doc_id=check_completion(access_token, report_id)

   
    if doc_id and doc_id != 'FATAL' and doc_id != 'CANCELLED':
        print("Status: Successful")
        report_url = get_report_data(access_token, doc_id, report_type)
        print(report_url)
    else:
        print(f"Status: {doc_id}")
        print("Sleeping for 60 seconds...")
        time.sleep(60)
        print("Retrying...")
        report_id, report_type = get_report(access_token)
        doc_id = check_completion(access_token, report_id)
        if doc_id and doc_id != 'FATAL' and doc_id != 'CANCELLED':
            print("Status: Successful")
            report_url = get_report_data(access_token, doc_id, report_type)
            print(report_url)
        else:
            print(f"Status: {doc_id}")
            print("Max retries exceeded.")
    
    # save_report_to_sql_database(report_url)
       

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        script()

Any idea where I might be going amiss in getting the report from Amazon sp-API?
